# How to keep track of column updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server to store users uploaded songs.

Each song has an id(simple auto increment number) and a name.

I want to use URL Rewriting to query some song, like this:

http://wwww.mysite.com/song/song_name

The problem is that I also want to enable users to change their songs name and still use the old URL.

I thought of creating another table whice will contain the old names and then check for some song name in both tables, is that a good solution?

Comment: Why not just add an (original) URL column?
And if user changes a name of his song 100 times before he sticks to the name he likes you want to have that song accessible by 100 URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach may be to create a single URL table that contains the URLs and the song it's tied to:

```
SongID:   URL:
1         song_name 
1         song_name_change
2         other_song_title
```

This approach would:

1. store as many URLs for each song as you need
2. simplify your query
3. potentially speed up your query by storing URL-formatted strings your your database (you mentioned you're just storing the song id and name, so I'm assuming you're formatting all titles like 'Song name' to 'Song_name' on-the-fly in the query)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the existing `songs` table I would:

- create a table `alias` with columns

  - `alias` - would contain song names, original and modified
  - `target` - id of the song, reference to `songs` table
- optionally, add the column `main_alias` to `songs` table; it would reference the main alias (i.e. the last edited one), so that when You can redirect people using old aliases or going to the song via its id.

Then, You could access the song via

- `URL/[song_id]` - **find song by id** + rewrite the URL to `main alias`
- `URL/old_song_name` - **find song by alias** + rewrite the URL to `main alias`
- `URL/new_song_name` - same as above
- `URL/even_newer_song_name` - same as above

All in all, you can have **unlimited number of names pointing to the same song**.

Answer (score 0):

Create table `song_names` with fields

- id
- song_id (key to `songs` table)
- name (name of the song, perhaps unique)
- creation_date (datetime when this name was created)

If you get a name of the song from link, you can find it in this table, so you can find a song in `songs` table. The actual song name will be the one in `song_names` table with given `song_id` and most recent `creation_date`.